# How do I import and use the python files in a view in django?

Tags: python, django

What I want to do is I'd like to call the module( `RSAtest` ) already created in view in Django. I am calling a function in RSAtest module from AboutPageView. But for some reason, it shows the following error:  **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp.functional'** Could you give me an idea how to use modules in Django?

```
# howdy/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from webapp.functional import RSAtest


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=None)

# Add this view
class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    RSAtest.main()
    #os.system('python3 howdy/RSAtest.py')
    template_name = "about.html"
```

Thanks for the any help.

Comment: Try adding the webapp to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: I did it.. but it is still not working.